# How can I integrate my ios app into the "Share out" pane in the iOS messages photo viewer?

Tags: ios, share, message, photos

I'm seeing a number of different applications appear in the "share out" pane that appears when you are messaged an image on iOS 6+ and would like to plop my application into there as well. How can I go about doing that? Here is a screenshot for clarification:

[image: The "share out" pane]

My app would take a place next to Catch or Evernote for example.

Thanks

Comment: Another Stackoverflow thread to answers that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Comment: @horak. i treid below solution but it doesnt worked for me. Can u share your plist file code pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to indicate that your app can open image files. This is done in the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Images</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The above will allow your app to appear in the "open in" menu for images. If your app is selected, your app will be launched or brought to the foreground and the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` delegate method will be called. The URL will contain a reference to the image file.

Comment: Is this still possible for newer IOS versions?

Comment: Just checking, it looks like there have been a lot of sdk updates since this post. I was having some issues implementing but I think I figured out my issues.

Comment: I added the above key value pair in plist, but not able see my App when i want to share photo in Photos App.

Comment: The photos app doesn't allow for 3rd party apps. Submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @maddy. i tried above code into my project-info.plist file. i am not able to see my app. Can u tell me pls

Comment: @HituBansal If you have an issue, post your own question with all relevant details.

Comment: @maddy i already did this. but doesnot get relevant solution . See if u can help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432410/receive-url-in-ionic-for-ios